# using elasticsearch replications in django

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

The current setup is compose by 3 elastic search servers, of witch one is the master and the other 2 are slave, at least they define themselves as that.

It might happen that the master goes down, for any kind of problem, this means that elastic search is going to find a new elegible master and switch to this new one.

Currently the problem is that all my application on the frontend servers is totally not aware of this so it will keel making queries to the same backend, of course killing all my website because it will not answer. I had a look around but I was not able to find anything related to backend switch on the fly even related to the new Haystack 2.x.

Any suggestion?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be necessary to me to leave this to your application layer. Most probably you access ES through HTTP-REST requests, which means you can put any HTTP load balancer like Nginx in front of your ES servers which should also switch to another node if one times out.

Comment: I thought so but is not clear to me if in that case i have an update/insert on a random client instead of the master it is going to be replicated on the other nodes

Comment: Don't know you exact setup, but AFAIK replication should work in both directions. If you have any uncertainties about this, try it out?